# Give back/ Bring Back / Take Back / Put Back / Return Back

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between all these? Thank you

> Give back/ Bring Back / Take Back / Put Back / Return Back

Answer (score -1):

there are no pronouns here such as give **it** back, etc. so, I will answer this as is.

> **Give back**- means you return something to someone. Ex. You 'give back' money(something) to a friend(someone) because you owed them some.
>
> **Bring back-** this is a time-related phrasal verb. Ex. Bring back the dead, or bring back the old times.
>
> **Take back-**another phrasal verb, for instance, you did something and someone wants to return it to previous condition. Ex.take it back
>
> **Put back-**another phrasal verb and similar to 'take back'. In addition, something that is related to time/schedule ex.put back(moved)the vacation on another day.
>
> **Return back-**[no answer, seems redundant]